# Fetching EC2 Instances in Batches/Pages with Fog

Tags: ruby, fog

Is it possible to fetch EC2 in batches using the Fog gem? The Amazon API has support for NextToken, and MaxResults to enable this, but I can't seem to find this in Fog anywhere:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceStatus.html#API_DescribeInstanceStatus_RequestParameters

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get this by passing NextToken/MaxResults in to the describe_instance_status request for AWS connections, more details should be available here: https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/requests/compute/describe_instance_status.rb#L9

Comment: Ahh sorry, I posted the API docs for DescribeInstanceStatus, while I really meant to post DescribeInstances (I was looking at DescribeInstanceStatus because I knew that fog already had support for it :)) AFAICT there is no reference to these params here: https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/requests/compute/describe_instances.rb. This might be better suited for Github issues, I was just unsure if I had missed something.

Comment: Ah, ok. I kind of wondered (since it seemed like you were describing one thing but linking to another, I just went with it). I think you are correct that describe_instances doesn't yet support this. It certainly could though, just have to find somebody willing to do the legwork. Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone finds this later and/or is following along, the related pull request is here: https://github.com/fog/fog/pull/3354